# Odd UI bug in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: mac, xcode, user-interface, ios

I have this annoying UI bug when using Xcode 4.3.2. Every time I press the space bar, the whole text scroll view jumps. Does anyone know why this happens, or how to stop it?

**Edit:** Happens, for example, when I'm writing comments in the code and the sentence contains a space. IT can be anywhere on the document, even in the center, doesn't have to be at the bottom of the page. After it "jumps" it goes back to where it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when a source file is small. Adding a lot of
empty lines to the bottom of the page so it is more than a page or two could help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in situations where you're not inputting text anywhere, so there's nowhere for your <kbd>space</kbd> to go? And does it cause the current scrolling view to jump about one screenful down? If so, then that's pretty common behavior in lots of apps, across lots of OSes, for decades. It comes from the idea of a pager like the Unix `more` or GNU `less` commands, where you could hit <kbd>space</kbd> to see the next page of the text output you were reading. Many email clients, web browsers, document viewers (not editors, but maybe editors in read-only mode) do this. In fact, if you hit <kbd>space</kbd> right now in your browser, it will probably jump down a page (assuming you haven't put focus on a text input box).

Comment: valid suggestion, but this is not what is happening in my case.

Comment: @scordova88 Then can you post a screen recording of what you're seeing? (the built-in Quicktime Player can record screen movies)